# How to use knockoutjs binding on a Telerik editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, tinymce, knockout.js

I'm trying to implement edit in place functionality for a description field, where editing is done using the telerik mvc editor. The editor needs to be hidden unless the user clicks on a span representing the editable section, and once done, hide the editor and have the marked up entry be placed in the editable element.

I'm not sure where to apply the knockout binding so that whatever is entered into the telerik editor is shown in the span after the editor is hidden.The editor creates an iframe that contains the marked-up html that get's generated as the user enter's content. That markup is converted is stored as an html encoded value within a textarea that's just outside the iframe.

If tried adding a bind to the textarea generated, but don't see the span bound with data-bind = "text: imgDescr" updating.

Her'es the razor view

```
<div>
    <span data-bind="text: imgDescr"></span>
</div>
<div>
@{ Html.Telerik().Editor()
  .Name("editor")
  .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "height:400px"})
  .Encode(false)
  .Render();    
}
</div>
```

and the js

```
function appViewModel() {
    this.ImgName = ko.observable(helpText);
    this.ImgDescr = ko.observable(helpText);
}

$('t-raw-content').attr('data-bind', "value: ImgDescr");

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());
```

Any suggestions on how this could be done? I also looked into using tinyMCE, but I think the rendering is handled in a similar manner.

Comment: Are you sure that $('t-raw-content') is a correct jQuery selector. Should this be $('.t-raw-content') or $('#t-raw-content')??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the examples listed [here](http://loc.MediaItems.Select%28i%20=%3E%20new%20GalleryViewModel%28%28MediaItemImage%29%20i%29%29.ToList%28%29;) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/knockoutjs/72Rdxi6tX_c) and the bindings example for tinyMCE provided by knockout wiki [here](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings---tinyMCE) I was able to get the editor bound in the way I needed it.

Part of what I was missing was the jquery.tinymce.js script.

The binding was done in a custom binding as in the example above and the only line needed to do the binding was

```
   setTimeout(function() { $(element).tinymce(options); }, 0);
```

in the init section of the custom binding.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8EjX/) of what I had. It's not a completely working example within jsFiddle, but shows everything I had on my page.

Answer (score 0):

If your editor is tinymce editor (?) adding a bind to the textarea is not helpfull.
You may acces the editor content using `tinymce.get('editor_id').getContent();` and set it using `tinymce.get('editor_id').setContent('This is a demo text.');`